# Django ORM left join with nested condition?

Tags: mysql, django, rdbms

I am trying to build an ORM query in django. First please look at the database schema.

Meeting Table ( meeting_meeting )

```
+----+------+------+
| id | host | name |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | M1   |
|  2 |    8 | M2   |
|  3 |    1 | M3   |
|  4 |    1 | M4   |
+----+------+------+
```

Participans Table ( meeting_participants )

```
+----+------------+---------+
| id | meeting_id | user_id |
+----+------------+---------+
|  1 |          1 |       8 |
|  1 |          3 |       8 |
+----+------------+---------+
```

All I am trying to do is to generate a list of meeting that someone either created or joined. For example user 8 created only one meeting (M2) but joined on two meetings ( M1 & M3 ). So the query will return M1,M2 and M3 as Meeting QueryDict.

I have already done the query with pure sql.

```
SELECT DISTINCT meeting_meeting.id, meeting_meeting.* FROM meeting_meeting 
LEFT JOIN meeting_participants on meeting_participants.meeting_id = meeting_meeting.id 
and ( meeting_meeting.host_id = 8 OR meeting_participants.user_id = 8 )
```

I am just not sure how to do that with ORM in Django. I did find some reference about prefetch_related and select related but I can't seem to put the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
user_id = 8
Meeting.object.filter(Q(host_id=user_id)|Q(participants__user_id=user_id))
```

Reference: [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Hi garg, it's working but I am a bit confused. How did django decide which join it should use? Let's just say I wanna use inner join, what will be the query then?

Comment: Since you have a foreign key to the `meetings` table in the `participants` table, django makes the join on this field. You can refer to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) for more details.
You can look at the exact query formed by printing out `str(Meeting.object.filter(Q(host_id=user_id)|Q(participants__user_id=user_id)).query)`